# Import saved AzureRMContext still requires password

Tags: powershell, azure

I was using `Save-AzureRmProfile` for all my scripts to execute azure requests in parallel. I borrowed this idea from [auto login to azure with powershell/](https://4sysops.com/archives/auto-login-to-azure-with-powershell/)

I had to update my systems to latest version (AzureRM > 4) and despite the fact that the AzureRmProfile are now AzureRmContext cmdlets I still cannot use it as before.

Scenario

Open a PS console and execute

```
Save-AzureRmContext -Profile (Add-AzureRmAccount) -Path myprofile.json

# List my VMs
Get-AzureRmVm
```

Open a second PS console

```
Import-AzureRmContext -Path myprofile.json

# List my VMs
Get-AzureRmVm
Get-AzureRmVM : Your Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired, please run Login-AzureRMAccount to set up your Azure credentials.
```

How can I reuse my profile to be loaded in parallel executions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug in the cmdlets. Not much you can do (only downgrade).

Track it here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/3954

Comment: Thanks @4c74356b41 or did I need to say Lt5kA :) I have checked the github repo but haven't found it.

Comment: you are actually the first person to decrypt this, not that it makes things more clear, but still ;) @guillem

Comment: jaja @4c74356b41 that what I though once translating it but still it was clear

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of workarounds.

Simple, in memory workaround, would need to be added whenever you import a context:

```
$ctx = Import-AzureRmContext -Path <path-to-context>
$ctx.Context.TokenCache.Deserialize($ctx.Context.TokenCache.CacheData)
```

More complex workaround. This creates a permanent file,  TokenCache.dat, which, if present, may allow you to avoid this problem on a machine altogether.

In a new POSH window:

```
$ctx = Import-AzureRmContext -Path <path-to-saved-context>
$session = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance
$cacheFile = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($session.ProfileDirectory, $session.TokenCacheFile)
if (Test-Path $cacheFile) {
  $session.DataStore.CopyFile($cacheFile, ($cacheFile + ".bak"))
}

$session.DataStore.WriteFile( $cacheFile, [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Protect($ctx.Context.TokenCache.CacheData, $null, [System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::CurrentUser))
$session.TokenCache = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ProtectedFileTokenCache -ArgumentList $cacheFile
[Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext.TokenCache = $session.TokenCache
```

Note that this problem should be fixed in the next release

Comment: I like the "in memory" solution as it requires a minimum change in my scripts. This should be also referenced in the github issue

Comment: It is referenced at the bottom of the github issue, as is the expected release of the permanent fix (7/7)

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround until the issue is not fixed or I downgrade my PS installation I used

```
$azureAccountName ="my.email@example.com"
$Password = "12345678"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAccountName, $azurePassword)
```

Then in my parallel ScriptBlock I do a call like this to replace the broken import credentials

```
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred
```

Not the kind of solutions I'm proud of but... it did the trick.